# VimeoPro simple API?

Tags: api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I had a basic programme which take an vimeo url, grab the id and get json information about the video (via "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/"+id+".json" ) .

But now, the consumer is using videopro, and ofc , vimeopro don't work with the simple api.
So the question is: Is there a vimeoPro simple api? Where ? i didn't find it :s.

Had i to use the advances API who use OAuth (feel sad for so few thing)? Is there a simple API ? etc.

Thinqs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's seems that it's not possible for private video : see below

http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:118406.
https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple.

An other way is to use oEmbed.

Answer (score 2):

Vimeo PRO works just fine with the simple API. The issue with the simple API is that it will never contain private videos. So if your Vimeo PRO customer has public videos, those will be accessible.

To access private videos, we need to make sure you have permission to see the videos. This permission system is supported in the new API (developer.vimeo.com/api) with OAuth 2.

It sounds a little complicated at first, but it can be as easy as the simple API.

1. [Create an API APP](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps)
2. Generate a token on your app page under the Authentication header
3. Make an API request with the access token : https://api.vimeo.com/me?access_token=XXXXX

Comment: My bad, i didn't say that video where private. Thinqs anyway